# Inform potential clients about security vulnerabilities?

Tags: xss, sql-injection

We have a lot of open discussions with potential clients, and they ask frequently about our level of technical expertise, including the scope of work for our current projects. The first thing I do in order to gauge the level of expertise on staff they have now or have previously used is to check for security vulnerabilities like XSS and SQL injection. I have yet to find a potential client who is vulnerable, but I started to wonder, would they actually think this investigation was helpful, or would they think, "um, these guys will trash our site if we don't do business with them." Non-technical folks get scared pretty easily by this stuff, so I'm wondering is this a show of good faith, or a poor business practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that surprising people by suddenly penetration-testing their software may bother people if simply for the fact that they didn't know ahead of time. I would say if you're going to do this (and I believe it's a good thing to do), inform your clients ahead of time that you're going to do this. If they seem a little distraught by this, tell them the benefits of checking for human error from the attacker's point of view in a controlled environment. After all, even the most securely minded make mistakes: the Debian PRNG vulnerability is a good example of this.

Comment: But if they're not protecting against it normally are they the right people to be developing the software?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a fairly subjective decision and different prospects would react differently if you told them.

I think an idea might be to let them know after they have given business to someone else.

At least this way, the ex-prospect will not think that you are trying to pressure them into giving you the business.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with this would be, that it would be quite hard to do checks on XSS without messing up their site.  Also, things like SQL injection could be quite dangerous. If you stuck with appending selects, you might not have too much of a problem, but then the question is, how do you know it's even executing the injected SQL?

Answer (score 0):

From the way you described it, it seems like a poor business practice that could be a beneficial one with some modification.

First off, **any** vulnerability assessment or penetration test you conduct on a customer should be agreed upon **in writing** by that customer, period. This covers your actions legally. Without a written agreement, if you inadvertently cause damage (application crash, denial-of-service, data leak, etc) during your inspection, you are liable and could be charged (under US law; other countries have different standards).

Even if you do not cause damage, a clueless or potentially malicious customer could take you to court claiming damages; a clueless judge might just award them.

If you have written authorization to do so, then a free vulnerability assessment to attract potential customers sounds like a show of good faith and demonstrates what you want -- your skills.